# How Can I Change The Text By Touching Anywhere Of The Screen In SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, ipados

Hello everyone I want to change the text randomly by touching anywhere but I can just change it by touching the text.

```
var myArray = ["1", "2", "3"]

@State private var selectedSuggestion = Int.random(in: 0...2)

var body: some View {
    
    Text(myArray[selectedSuggestion])
        .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 1, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 1)
        .font(.largeTitle)
        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
        .onTapGesture {
            self.selectedSuggestion = Int.random(in: 0...2)
            
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to add content shape

```
Text(myArray[selectedSuggestion])
    .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 1, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 1)
    .font(.largeTitle)
    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
    .contentShape(Rectangle())              // << here !!
    .onTapGesture {
        self.selectedSuggestion = Int.random(in: 0...2)

}
```